# C# OleDb Exception “No value given for one or more required parameters” while trying to search from Access database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm trying to search for input value on an Access Database using a Windows Form Application, and the found results should be displayed in text boxes. But I keep getting this error.

Here is my code:

```
private void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            string search = "";
            SearchForm popup = new SearchForm();
            DialogResult dialogresult = popup.ShowDialog();
            if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                search = SearchForm.item;
                
                if (search != "")
                {
                    Access_Connections.sql = "SELECT * FROM Learners WHERE @val IN(ID, Learner_name, Learner_surname, Grade, School, Gender, Blood_group, Home_language, Church_relation, Hostel_block);";

                    Access_Connections.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", search);

                    Access_Connections.cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    Access_Connections.cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    Access_Connections.cmd.CommandText = Access_Connections.sql;
                    Access_Connections.cmd.Connection = Access_Connections.con;

                    Access_Connections.openConnection();

                    Access_Connections.rd = Access_Connections.cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (Access_Connections.rd.Read())
                    {
                        text_name.Text += Access_Connections.rd["Learner_name"].ToString();
                        text_surname.Text += Access_Connections.rd["Learner_surname"].ToString();
                        text_grade.Text += Access_Connections.rd["Grade"].ToString();
                        text_school.Text += Access_Connections.rd["School"].ToString();

                    }

                    Access_Connections.closeConnection();
                }
                else if (dialogresult == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You clicked either Cancel or X button in the top right corner");
                }
                popup.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You add the parameter and then immediately clear the parameters...

Comment: There is something wrong with your connection string.

Comment: Also: if an exception is thrown, the `closeConnection()` function won't run, leaving the database file locked open. Put the connection inside a `using` block!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have turned it upside-down:

```
"SELECT * FROM Learners WHERE (Learner_name=@val OR Learner_surname=@val OR Grade=@val OR School=@val OR Gender=@val OR Blood_group=@val OR Home_language=@val OR Church_relation=@val OR Hostel_block=@val);"
```